# How to render different CSS classes in each element using v-for

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component, chartist.js

I'm trying to iterate trough the array of labels for a donut chart using chartist.js, I was unable to figure out if chartist.js can place the labels on the side instead of inside the donut chart. I want to pass a different css class on each element rendered by the v-for so that I can get the same color of the donut chart into its corespondent label. So if in the chart the value of x is color blue I want my label for x to have a blue color bullet point.

```
    <v-flex sm-6 style="margin-top: 15px;">
      <v-layout v-for="(item, index) in labelsAndValuesPieChart.labels" :key="index">
```

// Here is my "bullet point that I want to change color on each iteration

```
        <v-flex>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex>
          <span class="pie-chart-label">{{item}}</span>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
```

Comment: Where / how is the colour represented?

Comment: chartist.js has their own classes with different colors for example: .ct-series-a .ct-slice-pie, .ct-series-a .ct-slice-donut-solid, .ct-series-a .ct-area {
  fill: #d70206; }

Comment: Sorry, my question may not have been clear - is the colour within `item`? For example, could you output it with `{{item.color}}`?

Comment: no but I can make a separate array with the colors in it

Comment: Okay, I'm just wondering how you link `item` to the colour you need to output. For example, I would have said `:class="'pie-chart-label-' + item.color"`, but without that direct link...

Comment: Right now the item that I want to change color is the span with the class="dot" chartist classes are like .ct-series-a for index 0 .ct-series-b for index 1 and it just changes the letter alphabetically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments you have left underneath your question, you just need to generate classes that look like `ct-series-b`.

In that case, you could create an array that stores all of the letters (to be used for index to letter conversion). The index of the array will match the index of item;

```js
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] // ...

methods: {
  getClass: function(index){
    return 'ct-series-' + alphabet[index];
  }
}
```

```html
<v-flex>
   <span class="pie-chart-label" :class="getClass(index)">{{item}}</span>
</v-flex>
```

Comment: @Lewis Could you please flesh this answer out a bit?  I don't understand how to implement it.  The top part is clearly JS, but where does the v-flex stuff go?  The HTML is generated by the JS, so I'm not understanding how to add the `v-flex` stuff to HTML.

Comment: @StephenR Hi Stephen, the Original Author of the question is using [VueJS components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) - `<v-flex>` represents one such component, with a high probability that it's from [this framework](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids)

Comment: Ah. Thanks.  I guess I'll have to ask a new question then